# Does Metropolis advocate for Social Democracy?

Tags: analysis, metropolis

Metropolis (1927) talks about the importance of a mediator between the hand and the head. In the movie the head is the capitalists and the hand is the workers. A core aspect of Social Democracy and the Nordic model in Scandinavian countries is the importance of dialogue between trade unions and employees organizations, a mediator of sorts. So does Metropolis advocate for Social Democracy?
[Metropolis Restored](http://www.nytimes.com/2010/05/05/movies/05metropolis.html?_r=0)

Comment: Welcome to Movies & TV. Nice question, seeing the time period and cultural/political backdrop it was made in, that interpretation isn't too unlikely afterall.

Comment: It's too bad that the full film isn't available any more.  I wonder if this would be easier to intuit if the original cut were still available.

Comment: @Catija I thought that they had done a [near complete reconstruction in 2010](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis_%281927_film%29#Restorations), I actually watched it on TV this way. Is there anything significant lacking in that version?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I actually just saw that... I graduated from Film school in 2010, so the last time I thought about *Metropolis* was before they did the newest reconstruction.  The Wiki does say that there are still a couple of scenes missing because even the newly discovered film was very badly damaged. I wonder if many people have seen the newer reconstruction.

Answer (score 2):

No, not particularly regarding a mediator. A mediator between the working class and the capital is not an exclusive feature of social democracy and the scandinavian model is a sub category of social democracy. There's rather a strong reference to Marx regarding the revolte. The movie is rather slightly adovcating left-winged politics in general. He might have been favoring social democracy over marxism regarding the outcome of the revolte. This might have been an indirect comment on Marx.